# Add New Event in Modern SharePoint Calendar

Tags: listview, sharepoint, calendar, default, attachment

I have created a new calendar view from a SharePoint list and have enabled the attachments as well.
When I click + New from the top, I can see the attachment option, but on the other hand if I click + new on hovering my mouse from within the day cell in the calendar, there is no attachment option showing. Please help.

The attachment option is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This issue cannot be reproduced from my end. Please check as following to narrow down the issue:

1. Test readding the calendar web parts on a new page.
2. Test using a new calendar list.
3. Try cleaning up browser cache & cookies and test again.